# Can Kong rate limit per endpoint?

Tags: rate-limiting, kong, api-gateway

I can configure Kong's [rate limiting plugin](https://getkong.org/plugins/rate-limiting) so it enforces limits on each endpoint in a given API like this:

```
$ curl -X POST http://kong:8001/apis/{api}/plugins \
    --data "name=rate-limiting" \
    --data "config.second=5"
```

However, I'd like to configure different rate limits *per endpoint*. For example, I'd like to allow:

- `http://localhost:8000/endpoint1` to use a rate limit of 5 requests/second per IP
- `http://localhost:8000/endpoint2` to use a rate limit of 10 requests/second per IP

Is this possible with Kong? I see an [open issue](https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/505) related to this, but are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Could you make each endpoint into a Kong API, then apply rate-limiting per-API?

Answer (score 1):

Until Kong .13, this was not possible. However, in [Kong .13](https://github.com/Kong/kong) the [API object](https://getkong.org/docs/0.13.x/admin-api/#api-object) has been broken into 2 parts, [routes](https://getkong.org/docs/0.13.x/admin-api/#route-object) and [services](https://getkong.org/docs/0.13.x/admin-api/#service-object).

Using these tools, you should be able to apply different plugins for different endpoints in your API.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: Sure! Generally speaking, you'll first add a [service](https://getkong.org/docs/0.13.x/admin-api/#service-object) for your upstream API. This is where incoming requests will be routed. next, you'll ant to add a [route](https://getkong.org/docs/0.13.x/admin-api/#route-object) that covers the entire API and tie it to the service. Then, simply add another route for the endpoint you want a different rate limit on. Finally, add a rate limiter for JUST the route you added second.

Answer (score 0):

Kong cannot work on IP mode I believe. But to over come that you have combination of authentication and rate limiting.
With the combination of this you can say

```
API 1 - limited to 5 request/second for consumer 1
API 1 (again) - limited to 10 request/second for consumer 2
API 2 - limited to 25 request/second from consumer 1
```

To achieve this you need to enable authentication in the kong for the APIs you want to control and then assign the rates for each consumer/api.

This will give you benefit of controlling the request from consumers so that they will not be able to do extra request from multiple IPs. (if you want)